# How to achieve correctly encoded output with scriptcs?

Tags: c#, character-encoding, scriptcs

I'm trying to write cyrillic symbols to output:

```
// scr.csx
using System;
Console.WriteLine("asd ПРИВЕТ");
```

But it is not displayed as expected when I run it:

```
> scriptcs scr
asd ??????
```

I've tried to save `scr.csx` in different encodings, it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before outputting:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```