# How to run C# in Sublime Text 3 in Windows

Tags: c#, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I wanted to run C# in Sublime Text3, so I have installed sc"scriptcs"  But when I am running code terminal types

"scriptcs" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�

��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]

[cmd: ['scriptcs', '-script', 'D:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Проекты\\project', '-cache', 'false']]

[dir: D:\Users\User\Desktop\Проекты]

[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\Users\User\Downloads\setup_espeak-1.48.04;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\torch\lib;C:\Users\User\.dotnet\tools]

If you dont know what to do with sc"scriptcs". you can tell another way to run C# code in sublime

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Guessing from your username in cyrilic  in your path presumably it tries to shows things in terminal in your systems encoding(presumably a single byte encoding specific to eastern europe) while it should be utf8. Similiar problem(and solution) shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496289/how-to-achieve-correctly-encoded-output-with-scriptcs

Comment: For starters, [scriptcs](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs), if that's what you mean, was abandoned 5 years ago. It's unclear what you mean by `run C# in Sublime Text3` as *running* C# projects is done using `dotnet run`. To use ST for development you need OmniSharp. That's the same backend used by VS Code. There are sublime packages that install and use OmniSharp, eg [LSP-OmniSharp](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-OmniSharp)